# How do you refer to a 50 Euro bill in German?

Tags: colloquial

One can definitely say simply “50 Euro” or “50-Euro-Schein”, but is there some sort of colloquialism like *eine Fünfzig*, analogous to *a fifty* in English?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypz62CB63ws

Comment: @sollniss: "Das kostet 50 Euro" kann nicht durch "Das kostet 50-Euro-Schein" ersetzt werden, und "Gib mir mal einen 50-Euro-Schein" nicht durch "Gib mir mal einen 50 Euro". Also was ist die Frage? "50 Euro bill" kann ein Schein sein, aber auch eine Rechnung. Was ist gefragt?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Ein Fünfziger* is very often used to refer to a 50 Euro bill (at least where I live), as well as *ein Zehner* (10 Euro), *ein Zwanziger* (20 Euro) and *ein Hunderter* (100 Euro). Another term would be *[Fuffziger](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fuffziger)*.

I also sometimes hear the term *ein [Fuffi](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fuffi)* for a 50 Euro bill (but those are mostly on TV).
*Fuffi* is colloquial in some parts of Germany. These names were already used before the currency conversion from Deutsche Mark to Euro. Elder citizens might refer to coins in the same way they did at that times: *Groschen* (10 Pfennig, now rarely used for 10 cent).

Back when we had Schilling in Austria, I often heard and used the terms *[Zehnerl](http://wetog.com/bilder/data/media/1/075_10_groschen.jpg)* (10 Groschen) or *[Fünfzigerl/Fuffzgerl](http://www.austriancoins.com/images/19452005/Groschen/1997-50G.jpg)* (50 Groschen) when referring to Groschen coins. Since the Euro, I haven't really heard or used those terms. I usually just hear "XX Cent" or "XX Cent-Stück".

Comment: Heh, that's funny - the pronounciation of "Zehner" (cēneris) is still sometimes (though rarely) used as a slang word for 10-something(roubles/lats/euro) bills in Latvia, not sure though about which time that was introduced in; could be WW2 times or could be still from the 19th century.

Comment: As a side note, a "fuffi" can also refer to a certain amount of drugs in the value of 50 Euros, so be careful in which environment you use the term.

Comment: I disagree with the comment by @O.R.Mapper. It is precisely in order to avoid this ambiguity that the diminutive is usually used (in Austria, at least) for coins smaller than one Euro, i.e. Zwanziger**l** and Fünfziger**l** for 0,20 € and 0,50 € respectively.

Comment: @Em1: I am rather familiar with the coin meaning, in sentences such as "Wirf mal einen Zehner in den Automaten." That sounds like natural usage to me, whereas the interpretation of *Zehner/Zwanziger/Fünfziger* as banknotes border on "Gangstersprache" to me - it doesn't sound as bad as "Fuffi", but still like something I'd mostly expect from a clichéd movie than from actual people. Maybe that usage is specific to Southern Germany, though.

Comment: @Ingmar You don't even need diminuitives (never heard any, too), because the ambiguity is forced: Der Fünfziger <-> Der Schein. @ O.R. Note that "gangster" expressions can enter "normal" German, too. This is far from gangster, though.

Comment: Comments cleaned up - please try to include valuable content of comments in exisiting answers, or write own answers. Lengthy discussions on a topic should got to [chat]. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Also in Austria you will hear »Fünfziger« for a 50 Euro bill. The same pattern is true for all bills:

- Fünfer (5 €)
- Zehner (10 €)
- Zwanziger (20 €)
- Fünfziger (colloquial also »Fuffziger«) (50 €)
- Hunderter (100 €)
- Zweihunderter (200 €)
- Fünfhunderter (500 €)

Before we used Euro, our currency in Austria was Schilling, and in those times we had bills with bigger numbers (but less value):

- Tausender (1000 Schilling)
- Fünftausender (5000 Schilling)

The word »Fuffi« is not common in Austria. I never heard it before.

There is the term »falscher Fuffziger« which literally means a fake 50 Euro bill, but is also used in the meaning of »insincere Person«. In this term you never say »Fünfziger«. As far as I know, this is true also in Germany.

In eastern parts of Austria there is a slang word for »Hunderter«, mainly used by shady persons: It is »Kilo«. This is interesting, because the greek word χίλιοι (chílioi), which is the origin of »Kilo«, has the meaning »thousand«. But as a thieves' cant word it has the meaning of a 100 Euro bill.

»Groschen« was in Austria the official name of the hundredth of 1 Schilling. So since we don't have Schilling and Groschen any more, we don't use the word »Groschen« for Euro-Cent or any other amounts of our "new money".

Comment: @chirlu: Dein Edit war im Grunde schon ok, aber »öS« (kleines ö, großes S) war niemals eine offizielle Abkürzung für Schilling. Die offizielle Abkürzung war »ATS«, ebenfalls in Gebrauch waren »OES« und »ÖS« (mit großem Ö), allerdings war das Standard-Währungssymbol auf Rechnungen, Preisschildern usw. einfach nur »S«. Daher habe ich nun die Abkürzung durch das ausgeschriebene Wort ersetzt.

Comment: Das war ich gar nicht, das war @Matthias. :-) (Der aber damit das völlig falsche _€_ aus einem Bearbeitungsvorschlag korrigiert hat.) Ausgeschrieben ist auf jeden Fall gut.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wenn Du Dir da so sicher bist, dann korrigiere bitte https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreichischer_Schilling, denn von da habe ich es übernommen.

Answer (score 0):

*Fünfziger* is correct. *Fuffi* would only be used in a faux mockery context. *Fünfziger/Zehner* almost always indicates the Euro notes (or Mark, in the past). I’ve never heard them being used for Cent (or *Pfennig*) coins.

Comment: Without context, I would primarily associate *Fünfziger/Zwanziger/Zehner/Fünfer* etc. with the respective Cent coins, not with Euro banknotes - possibly, because the less significant coin sums lend themselves more to informal/joking language than the more "serious" banknote sums? As [this](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/rhein-main/frankfurt/schule-zehn-cent-fuer-den-gang-auf-die-schultoilette-1277809.html) and [this](http://www.abendblatt.de/politik/ausland/article1577305/Praegend-Papst-Benedikt-XVI-auf-50-Cent-Muenze.html) example show, that interpretation of *Fünfziger* etc. does exist, too.

Comment: East Germany first thinks Cent/Pfennig when hearing "Fünfziger"

Comment: It should be noted that Duden lists both the banknote and the coin meanings as colloquial meanings of [Zehner](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zehner), [Zwanziger](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zwanziger_Muenze_Geldschein) and [Fünfziger](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fuenfziger).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Because of the phrasing "einen **runden** Zehner", I don't think this is a good example. It could refer to the number itself, which is then made into a coin by adding the adjective "round".

Comment: The second example is similarly unsuitable, as it has "Benedikt-" preceding it.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: So, in the first example, you agree that *Zehner* can equally denote Euros and Cents because it refers primarily to the unqualified number? I have some doubts about your interpretation of *round*, though, as with respect to numbers, *rund* mostly refers to mathematical rounding (here, as a way to express that it's exactly 10, not 11, not 10.5).

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Concerning the second example, you noted correctly that *Benedikt-* appears in the sub-headline, but where in the sentence "Denn dann steigen die Chancen, dass er einen blitzeblanken, goldglänzenden kleinen Fünfziger mit Papstporträt als Wechselgeld bekommt." is *Fünfziger* preceded by *Benedikt-*?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Here you have "goldglänzend" and "klein" making the abstract 50 a coin - the writer seems to fear that otherwise, people will primarily think of the banknote. @ Previous comment: No, I believe that *Fünfziger* primarily denotes the banknote (because of the gender-congruence with *Schein*). However, perhaps there exists a somewhat serious article using *Fünfziger* **standalone** to denote the coin.

Answer (score 0):

This question is lacking both an answer from the German and one from the Swiss point of view. I can provide the German, but I hope that somebody from Switzerland can step up for the Swiss.

---

As in Austria, all banknotes<sup>[1]</sup> can be referred to by their value with a following *-er*.

5 € – Fünfer
10 € – Zehner
20 € – Zwanziger
50 € – Fünfziger
100 € – Hunderter
200 € – Zweihunderter
500 € – Fünfhunderter
1000 DM – Tausender (there is currently no 1000 € note).

Note that the way *Fünfziger* is pronounced will vary depending on where the speaker is from. Unfortunately, the [*Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f16/) only lists the variants for *fünfzehn*, so I didn’t include the map directly; but it is rather safe to assume that *fünfzig* will be pronounced similarly.

For coins is where it gets confusing. In the North of Germany,<sup>[2]</sup> they will carry the same name as a corresponding banknote — this is explicitly excluding the 1 and 2 cent and 1 and 2 € coins. In the North, these usually du not have any specific name at all.

In the South, especially where Bavarian or Swabian is spoken, diminutives are used for coins of less than 1 € value — similar to their usage in Austria.

1 ¢ – Einerl(e)
2 ¢ – Zweierl(e)
5 ¢ – Fünferl(e)
10 ¢ – Zehnerl(e)
20 ¢ – Zwanzigerl(e)
50 ¢ – Fünfzigerl(e)

In Bavarian, the 1 and 2 € coins are also referred to as *Iggl* and *Zwiggl* respectively. *Zwiggl* seems to be a contraction of *zwei Iggl*. I cannot, unfortunately, provide you with any information on the etymology of *Iggl*. In D-Mark times, the diminutive *Maggl* was commonly used for the 1 Mark coin alongside *Iggl*.

Finally, the 10 cent coin — and its predecessor, the 10 Pfennig coin — are special cases, that are most easily explained with this map from the [*Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r8-f2a-2/):

[image: map with different regional names of the ten cent coin]

As you can see, in the North the terms *Groschen* and *Zehner* are used exchangeably, while the South uses variations of *Zehnerl(e)*. Some Southerners will not understand you if you say *Groschen* — but most Northerners will correctly deduce what a *Zehnerl* could be.

---

[1] Sorry, OP, but I speak British English.
[2] My guess is either the [*Speyerer Linie*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speyerer_Linie_%28Isoglosse%29) or maybe even the [*Karlsruher Linie*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karlsruher_Linie).