# Regionale Unterschiede: Ist ein "Zehner" ein Schein oder eine Münze?

Tags: regional

**Auf den Punkt gebracht**:

Diese Frage ist angeregt durch Diskussionen zur Frage [How do you say in German 50 euros bill?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/17906/1224).

Meine Frage vereinfacht lautet:
*Was ist mit "Zehner" gemeint ist: Ein Zehneuroschein oder ein Zehncentstück?*

**Vollständige Frage**:

Vorneweg sei kurz erwähnt, dass ich der Einfachheit halber die Variante "Zehncentmünze" außen vor lasse und immer nur von "Zehncentstück" spreche. Außerdem verwende ich als Beispiel immer die "10", womit ich die Frage aber nicht auf diese beschränke.

Ich lebe in Westdeutschland (als grobe Orientierung Raum Köln) und ich kenne das so, dass Centstücke immer und einzig in der Form "Zehncentstück" angegeben werden. Scheine können dagegen sowohl als "Zehneuroschein" oder als "Zehner" bezeichnet werden. Soweit ich mich erinnern kann, galt dies auch schon zu der Zeit, als es den Euro noch nicht gab, da natürlich mit Mark bzw. Pfennig<sup>1</sup>.

Benötige ich also eine bestimmte Münze, sage ich:

> Hast du noch ein Zehncentstück?

Benötige ich hingegen einen Schein, so stehen mir zwei Möglichkeiten zur Verfügung:

> Hast du noch einen Zehneuroschein?
> Hast du noch einen Zehner?

Da es keine Centstücke im Wert von 100 oder mehr gibt und folglich "Hunderter", "Zweihunderter" etc. nur Scheine bezeichnen können, erschließt sich mir die Logik, dass man konsequenterweise mit Werten kleiner als 100 auch immer die Scheine meint.

Anscheinend wird aber in anderen Regionen ein Zehncentstück als "Zehner" bezeichnet. Folgende Zitate habe ich aus den Kommentaren zu der anderen Frage entnommen:

> [O. R. Mapper](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17906/how-do-you-say-in-german-50-euros-bill/17907?noredirect=1#comment40962_17926): Without context, I would primarily associate Fünfziger/Zwanziger/Zehner/Fünfer etc. with the respective Cent coins, not with Euro banknotes
>
> [falkb](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17906/how-do-you-say-in-german-50-euros-bill/17907?noredirect=1#comment40968_17926): East Germany first thinks Cent/Pfennig when hearing "Fünfziger"

Von einigen wurde angemerkt, dass es kontextabhängig ist. Der Punkt ist mit Sicherheit nicht verkehrt. Wenn mich jemand nach einem "Zehner" fragt und ich weiß, dass nur ein "Zehncentstück" gemeint sein kann, so suche ich nach einer Münze.
Und dennoch: Stehe ich vor einem Automaten, der nur Münzen annimmt, und würde noch 10 Cent benötigen, so würde ich immer nach einem "Zehncentstück" fragen und niemals "Zehner" sagen. Denn für mich ist ein "Zehner" auch dann immer noch ein Schein.

Und bei fehlendem Kontext ist "Zehner" erst recht immer der Schein – für mich.

Meine konkrete Frage ist: **Wo wird was wie bezeichnet?**

Es geht mir hierbei lediglich um die Form "Zehner" und was damit bezeichnet wird.
Slangbegriffe, veraltete Begriffe oder sonstige umgangssprachliche Formen wie "Fuffi", "(falscher) Fuffziger", "Groschen" möchte ich im Rahmen dieser Frage bitte ausschließen. Abweichungen bedingt durch Dialekte sind OK, vorausgesetzt sie basieren auf der standarddeutschen Variante.

PS: Es würde mich freuen, wenn mal ein paar Kommentare oder Antworten aus dem Norden kommen. Der Süden und Österreich wurden schon zur Genüge abgedeckt.

---

<sup>1</sup> Nicht ganz sicher bin ich mir, was zu Zeiten der DM mit einem "Fünfer" gemeint war, da es sowohl eine Fünfmarkmünze als auch einen Fünfmarkschein gab. Mein Gefühl sagt mir aber, dass damit in meiner Region der Schein gemeint war.

---

An diejenigen, die auf diese Frage antworten oder kommentieren: Es wäre hilfreich, wenn eine Regionsangabe gemacht wird, und wenn es nur Nord-, West-, Ost- oder Süddeutschland ist.

Comment: Nicht beantwortbar, da kontextabhängig: Wühlt einer in einem Haufen Münzen, kann er durchaus mit "Zehner" die Münze meinen. I.d.R. ist damit aber der Schein gemeint.

Comment: @falkb Interessant ist, dass ich dich mit der Aussage "Fünfziger == Cent" zitiere und du jetzt für den "Zehner" gegensätzliches sagst.

Comment: Ich kenne es so: *Zehner* =Schein; *Zehnerle* =Münze

Comment: Also ich kenne Zehner = Schein, Zehnerl = Münze (Oberösterreich)

Comment: @Em1: ja, hier in Mitteldeutschland sagt man dann eher Groschen bei der Münze. Es folgt wohl keiner Logik.

Comment: Ich denke mal, Groschen löst das Verwechslungsproblem und wird deswegen gern genommen. Aber die Leute denken wohl eher in kleinen Einheiten, deswegen bei Fünfziger eher der Gedanke an 50 Cent/Pfennig, wobei natürlich dann doch das große Geld gemeint sein kann. :-P

Comment: Die Bezeichnung "Groschen" habe ich in meinem Umfeld (NRW/Niedersachsen) in Bezug auf Zehncentstücke noch nie gehört. Die Verwendung des Wortes hat in meinem Bekanntenkreis abrupt mit der Euroeinführung aufgehört. Für mich ist es deshalb gleichbedeutend mit "zehn Pfennig" (also der DM-Münze). Ich muss aber dazusagen, dass ich das sehr schade finde... Die generische Bezeichnung {x}centstück hat irgendwie keinen Charme.

Comment: Ich halte das nicht für abhängig von der Region, sondern vom Kontext. Ein Fünfer kann ein Schein oder eine Münze sein, ein Achter ein Ruderboot mit oder ohne Steuermann.

Comment: Es gibt Euro-Münzen?! ;)

Comment: Groschen hat nichts mit der Währungseinheit zu tun. Es ist einfach der Zehner im kleinen Geld. Ich habe selbst bei älteren Leuten keine Veränderung im Gebrauch bemerkt. Der Begriff Groschen ist sogar äußerst hilfreich, um genau diese hier angesprochene Verwechslung zwischen Schein und Münze zu umgehen.

Comment: @falkb Seit Einführung des Euros höre ich "Groschen" nahezu nur noch von jenen Leuten, die auch heute noch "Mark" als Währungseinheit verwenden. Sprich alte Leute, die es nicht auf die Reihe bekommen. Ansonsten ist der Begriff gefühlt ausgestorben. Aus der Menge der Antworten und Kommentare hier und bei der anderen Frage, ist mir aber durchaus bewusst, dass dies nicht für alle Regionen zustimmt. Verwechslungsgefahr zwischen Schein und Münze ist für mich sowieso ausgeschlossen, eben weil es hier immer eindeutig ist. "Zehner" = Schein.

Comment: @Em1: Wo ist dein "hier"? Jedenfalls nicht bei mir hier... ;)

Comment: @falkb Also grobe Orientierung Köln. Hab ich aber auch in der Frage mitangegeben.

Comment: @Em1: vielleicht hilft diese Karte weiter, wo zu sehen ist, dass der Begriff Groschen im Osten deutlich mehr gebraucht wird: http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_8/r8_f2a/ Das würde Köln auch mit erklären. Wikipedia sagt übrigens auch, dass es nach der Euro-Umstellung weiter verwendet wird (siehe http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groschen#Deutschsprachiger_Raum)

Comment: @falkb Vor allen Dingen interessant finde ich hier wieder die Grenze entlang des Mains. Ich habe sowas schon vermutet, und ich bin mir sicher, dass wir die Karte dort auf die Fragestellung hier übertragen können. Dennoch verwundert mich es, dass laut dieser Karte in meiner Gegend "Zehner" für eine 10-Cent-Münze gesagt wird. Dem würde ich nämlich überhaupt nicht zustimmen.

Comment: @Em1: Du musst sicherlich auch die soziale Schicht berücksichtigen...

Answer (score 9):

Ich beziehe mich auf Österreich:

Als es noch keinen Euro, sondern Schilling gab, war ein »Zehner« eine 10-Schilling-Münze, denn es gab niemals einem 10-Schilling-Schein. Da war die Sache also mangels Alternativen klar. Ebenso war der »Fünfer« immer eine 5-Schilling-Münze.

(Kurzer Exkurs: Der »Fünfer« war und ist auch eine Straßenbahnlinie, eine Schulnote oder prinzipiell alles, was in Deutschland »eine Fünf« genannt werden würde; Gleiches gilt für alle Zahlwörter. Malt jemand die Ziffer »9« auf die Tafel, ist das in Österreich keine Neun, sondern ein Neuner.)

Ein »Zehnerl« war eine 10-Groschen-Münze, ein »Fuffzigerl« eine 50-Groschen-Münze, ein »Fünferl« eine 5-Groschen-Münze und ein »Zweierl« war eine 2-Groschen-Münze.
Die 1-Schilling-Münze hieß einfach »Schilling« und die 1-Groschen-Münze war umgangssprachlich ein »Groscherl«. (»Groschen« war die Währungseinheit, aber keine spezielle Münze.)

2-Schilling-Münzen gab es nur vor dem 2. Weltkrieg, 20-Groschen-Münzen nur bis 1959, daher gab es zu meinen Lebzeiten (geboren 1965) diese Münzen nicht im Umlauf. Mir sind für diese Stückelungen keine eigenen Namen bekannt.

Mit dem »Zwanziger« war bis 1980 ausschließlich der 20-Schilling-Schein gemeint, denn bis dahin gab es keine 20-Schilling-Umlaufmünzen (wohl aber Sondermünzen, die man aber normalerweise nicht im Geldbörsl hatte).

Seit 1980 gab es dann auch 20-Schilling-Münzen, die zwar nicht besonders häufig im Umlauf waren, aber es waren ganz normale Umlaufmünzen (also keine Sondermünzen), die gleichzeitig mit den 20-Schilling-Scheinen existierten. Diese Münzen waren aber unter der Bevölkerung sehr unbeliebt. Jeder, der sie irgendwann zufällig bekam, versuchte sie so rasch wie möglich wieder loszuwerden.

Mit dem »Zwanziger« war daher auch von 1980 bis 2002 so gut wie immer der 20-Schilling-Schein gemeint, obwohl manchmal auch die 20-Schilling-Münze »Zwanziger« genannt wurde.

Jetzt, in Zeiten des Euro, gibt es keine 10-Euro-Umlaufmünzen (nur Sondermünzen für Sammler). Jetzt ist mit dem »Zehner« der 10-Euro-Schein gemeint, und der »Fünfer« ist der 5-Euro-Schein.

Den Begriff »Zweier« für die 2-Euro-Münze habe ich zwar schon gehört, aber da es nach dem Krieg keine 2-Schilling-Münze (und daher keinen Zweier) gab, will den meisten Österreichern auch bei den 2-Euro-Münzen das Wort »Zweier« nur mühsam von den Lippen kommen. Man spricht hier eher von »Zwei-Euro-Münzen«.

Die 1-Euro-Münze heißt »Euro«.

Die Cent-Münzen heißen nicht, wie man in Analogie zu den früheren Groschen-Münzen vermuten könnte »Fuffzigerl«, »Zwanzigerl« usw., sondern »Fuffzig Cent«, »Zwanzig Cent« usw. bis hinunter zu »Zwei Cent«. Die 1-Cent-Münze heißt aber nicht »Ein Cent«, sondern wird meist »Ein-Cent-Stück« genannt.

Comment: Großteils Zustimmung, bis auf den letzten Absatz: In meinem Umfeld sagt man zB sehr wohl zB Fünfziger**l**.

Answer (score 8):

Schwaben:

> Fü**m**ferle / Zehnerle / Zwanz'gerle / Fuffz'gerle: Münzen
>   Fünfer / Zehner /Zwanz'ger /...: primär Scheine

*Aber* die Aufteilung ist nicht absolut. Kontextabhängig kann ein Zehner auch die Münze sein, die am Automat runtergefallen ist....

Comment: Da es sich um einen (hoch)deutschen Begriff in dialektischer Färbung handelt und nicht um einen dialektspezifischen Ausdruck (wie "Breschtleng" = Erdbeeren), sah ich kein Problem. Deshalb auch die Überschrift "Schwaben", nicht "Schwäbisch". Charakteristisch hier in der Region ist der durchaus  hohe Anteil an dialektischer Färbung der Alltagssprache, ohne gleich "richtiger" Dialekt zu sein.

Comment: @userunknown - Em1 fragt explizit nach regionalen Unterschieden und da kommt der Dialekt uweigerlich ins Spiel.

Comment: Ich sehe, ich hatte das mit den Dialekten zu rasch überflogen und falsch aufgefasst. Bitte um Pardon.

Answer (score 2):

Meiner Erfahrung nach, vorrangig aus dem süddeutschen Raum, können Zahlen wie *Zehner*/*Zwanziger*/*Fünfziger* etc. gleichermaßen für Münzen und Scheine stehen, tendenziell kenne ich die Bezeichnung aber eher für Münzen, während Worte wie "Zehner" für Geldscheine gefühlsmäßig schon eher in Richtung der Ganovensprache aus Filmen gehen. Vielleicht liegt es daran, dass Scheine mit größeren Geldbeträgen korrespondieren, weshalb es weniger angemessen ist, hier eine flapsige Ausdrucksweise zu verwenden, als bei "unwichtigen" Münzen.

In Dialekten mag es durchaus so sein, dass man den (dialektabhängigen) Diminutiv für die Münzen und die normale Form für den Schein verwendet, jedoch ist die Verwendung des Diminutivs auf Hochdeutsch in der gesprochenen Sprache doch relativ ungewöhnlich (*Zehnerle* mag auf Schwäbisch natürlich klingen, aber von einem *Zehnerchen* oder gar einem *Zehnerlein* zu sprechen, klingt doch arg gekünstelt), sodass hier derselbe Begriff für Münze und Schein verwendet wird.

Der Duden führt für [Zehner](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Zehner), [Zwanziger](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Zwanziger) und [Fünfziger](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/F%C3%BCnfziger) beide Bedeutungen auf, für [Fünfer](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fuenfer) interessanterweise nur die Eurocentmünze, wobei es auch für das Wort *Fünfer* nicht ungewöhnlich ist, neben der Centmünze auch für den Schein zu stehen (z.B. [hier](http://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/der-neue-fuenf-euro-schein-wird-in-umlauf-gebracht-a-897676.html), [hier](http://www.n-tv.de/ratgeber/Der-neue-Zehn-Euro-Schein-ist-da-article13653506.html), [hier](http://www.welt.de/finanzen/article116219755/Automaten-spucken-neuen-Fuenfer-wieder-aus.html) und [hier](http://www.tagesschau.de/wirtschaft/fuenf-euro-schein102.html)).

Generell kommt es aber wohl auf den Kontext an, wenn man einen Zehner/Zwanziger/Fünfziger in einen Automaten *wirft*, ist es wohl die Münze, wenn man ihn *hineinschiebt*, ist es ein Schein.

Comment: Oh ja, der "Schwäbische Diminuitiv" - ein Klassiker für sich. Was kann der Schwabe nicht alles mit "-le" verniedlichen. Hundle, Zügle, Autole... Beim "Laschtwägele" haben wir den Großeltern unserer Kinder dann doch Grenzen gesetzt.

Comment: After this discussion I asked my kids (grown up in Swabia) if they knew the expression *Zehnerle* - they said they never heard it, all their friends will say *Zehn Cent*. This may indicate that indeed the diminutive is going to disappear over time.

Comment: @Stephie. Aber Autole sagt doch keiner :) Das ist das "heiligs Blechle"

Comment: @Harald: Nur wenn's den Stern vorne drauf hat! ;-)

Comment: Meiner Erfahrung aus dem süddeutschen Raum zufolge (Ober- & Niederbayern, Österreich, Oberpfalz) wird die normale -er-Endung *ausschließlich* für die Scheine benutzt. Ich kann mich bewusst an *einen einzigen* abweichenden Fall erinnern: in einem alten Film hätte jemand (ein Norddeutscher) statt einem "Zehner" lieber eine Mark gehabt. Für mich damals superverwirrend. Fazit: für mich klingt "Zehner" in der Verwendung für eine Münze entweder nach dem hohen Norden oder antiquiert.

Answer (score 2):

Aus dem Berliner Raum ist zu vermelden:

**Fünfer, Zehner, Zwanziger, Hunderter** sind Bezeichnungen für Scheine.

Münzen werden wie folgt betitelt:
1 = Ein Cent
2 = Zwei Cent
5 = Fünf Cent *oder* Sechser (analog zum Fünf-Pfennig-Stück)
10 = Zehn Cent *oder* Groschen

Unsicher bin ich mir bei 50 EUR / 50 Cent. Ich meine, dass das 50-Pfennig-Stück damals auch einen Spitznamen hatte, der is mir aber nicht geläufig.
Generell würde ich bei **Fuffziger/Fünfziger** aber wohl auch zuerst an einen Schein denken.

Comment: Hast du eine Referenz zu "Sechser"? Woher kommt das? Ist mir absolut unbekannt. Ansonsten stimmt deine Antwort aber mit dem überein, wie ich es kenne.

Comment: Sechser hat wohl historische Wurzeln als Hälfte eines Groschens, sagt das Internet. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sechsling